# iOS - keep layout in landscape but change controls

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, uikit, orientation

I'm done with the auto-layout stuff in my iOS universal App, and it's working perfectly in portrait. However, I want the user to be able to rotate the device and play the game in landscape mode. The problem I'm facing is that I don't want the layout to change at all, and only change the controls of the game (sliding up the screen should make the player go up in both orientations).

Thing is, I don't know how to prevent orientation from changing the layout and at the same time be able to change behaviour based on the orientation. Do you guys have any idea how I could manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did found a way to do, for future reference, when an orientation is disabled, we still can access device orientation (and not interface orientation), and register a notification to act upon change.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var currentOrientation = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         // Register for notification about device orientation change
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceDidRotate(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    // Remove observer on window disappears
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        if UIDevice.current.isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications {
            UIDevice.current.endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        }
    }

    // That part gets fired on orientation change, and I ignore states 0 - 5 - 6, respectively Unknown, flat up facing and down facing.
    func deviceDidRotate(notification: NSNotification) {
        if (UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue < 5 && UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue > 0) {
            self.currentOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue
        }
    }


}
```